# Cloth simulation not rendering properly

Tags: rendering, baking, cloth-simulation

I am using blender 2.8 and have a piece of cloth falling down on a collision object. In the render preview it displays well, however when i go to render the image the cloth glitches in some way.

[image: in rendered view]

[image: in preview mode]

Comment: With 2.8 being an in-development build it's difficult to pin the issue down to user error or software bug. Is this behavior reproduceable in blender 2.79?

Comment: I have solved the problem, it seemed to be a problem with the mesh object. I (re)converted it to a new mesh and re-applied the cloth simulation and the problem has now disappeared